# How to remove double quotes from a string from JSON response in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, bitcoin

I have a problem with the BlockChain API response. While getting the address from the wallet, the address is enclosed in double quotes like below. How to strip the quotes?

"1Dgyv8Qz1nkrJddoyLBepv1RUXSDqCBCdp"

Code:

```
$resp = file_get_contents($blockchain_receive_root . "v2/receive?key=" . $my_api_key . "&gap_limit=".$gap_limit. "&callback=" . urlencode($callback_url) . "&xpub=" . $my_xpub);
$response = json_decode($resp);

print json_encode($response->address);
```

Comment: Your question does not even show minimum effort to solve your problem. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or try using the search functionality first. Anyways, since this looks to be fairly an easy one, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to remove anything. The issue arises when you call `json_encode` over the string which adds the double quotes.

So just remove the `json_encode` call, and it should work like charm:

```
$resp = file_get_contents($blockchain_receive_root . "v2/receive?key=" . $my_api_key . "&gap_limit=".$gap_limit. "&callback=" . urlencode($callback_url) . "&xpub=" . $my_xpub);
$response = json_decode($resp);

print $response->address;
```